# How to get a list of all my subscriptions in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to get a list of all my subscriptions in Woocommerce. I have read about WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_subscription(), but I don't know how to use it. Please keep in mind that I have almost zero knowledge concerning PHP.

Someone asked a similar question on the forum. I finally used the following code:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Action']))
{
$Action = $_REQUEST['Action'];
switch($Action)
{
    case "ValidateSubscription":

        include('../../wp-load.php'); //Guessing this path based on your code sample... should be wp root

        $Subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_all_users_subscriptions();
        print_r($Subscriptions);
        break;
    default:
        echo "invalid action";
    }
}else
    {
    echo "no action specified";
}
?>
```

How can I use it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **wcs_get_users_subscriptions()**.  If you don't pass a user_id argument, the default is to get the current user. The function returns all subscriptions.